# Insert PHP data into JavaScript - Dynamic autocomplete magicsearch plugin used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to figure out [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select-Plugin-With-jQuery-magicsearch.html) plugin

Below code is given as plugin example

```
<section>
<input class="magicsearch" id="basic" placeholder="search names...">
</section>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var dataSource = [
                {id: 1, firstName: 'Tim', lastName: 'Cook'},
                {id: 2, firstName: 'Eric', lastName: 'Baker'},
                {id: 3, firstName: 'Victor', lastName: 'Brown'},
                {id: 4, firstName: 'Lisa', lastName: 'White'},
                {id: 5, firstName: 'Oliver', lastName: 'Bull'},
                {id: 6, firstName: 'Zade', lastName: 'Stock'},
                {id: 7, firstName: 'David', lastName: 'Reed'},
                {id: 8, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Hand'},
                {id: 9, firstName: 'Tony', lastName: 'Well'},
                {id: 10, firstName: 'Bruce', lastName: 'Wayne'},
            ];
            $('#basic').magicsearch({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
                id: 'id',
                format: '%firstName% · %lastName%',
                multiple: true,
                multiField: 'firstName',
                multiStyle: {
                    space: 5,
                    width: 80
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I have a working PHP code which echoes two rows from database into a multiple select box.

```
<?php
$usrqry = "SELECT userId, CONCAT(userFirst,' ',userLast) AS user FROM users WHERE userId != 1";
$usrres = mysqli_query($mysqli, $usrqry) or die('-1'.mysqli_error());
?>
<select id="users" multiple class="form-control selectall" size="4" name="userId[]">
<option value="all" selected><?php echo $allUsersOpt; ?></option>
<?php
while ($u = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usrres)) {
echo '<option value="'.$u['userId'].'">'.$u['user'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

I am trying to make this PHP code work with above JavaScript, Every solution I try end up into nothing

Comment: Look at here. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. it's simple and quite easy plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This will work ...

```
<section>
<input class="magicsearch" id="basic" placeholder="search names...">
</section>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var dataSource =[ 
            <?php
                $usrqry = "SELECT userId, CONCAT(userFirst,' ',userLast) AS user FROM users WHERE userId != 1";
                $usrres = mysqli_query($mysqli, $usrqry) or die('-1'.mysqli_error());

                while ($u = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usrres)) {
                echo "{id: '".$u['userId']."', name: '".$u['user']."'},";
                }
            ?>
            ];
            $('#basic').magicsearch({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                fields: ['id', 'name'],
                id: 'id',
                format: '%name%',
                multiple: true,
                multiField: 'name',
                multiStyle: {
                    space: 5,
                    width: 80
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @ mata : its not json, its just string `echo "{id: '".$u['userId']."', name: '".$u['user']."'},";`

Comment: when this get rendered on page this would be json.

Comment: I am sorry but , Guru's code is horrible and your suggestion is more horrible.

Comment: @mata I appreciate your help, But I haven't reached any solution

Answer (score 0):

Take data from php, first will get data from db

```
<?php
    $usrqry = "SELECT userId, CONCAT(userFirst,' ',userLast) AS user FROM users WHERE userId != 1";
    $usrres = mysqli_query($mysqli, $usrqry) or die('-1'.mysqli_error());
    $response = array();
    while ($u = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usrres)) {
        $response[] = ["id"=>$u['id'],"user"=>$u['user']];
    }
?>
```

Then get data in javascript as json

```
$(function() {
    var dataStr = "<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>";
    var dataSource = JSON.parse(dataStr);
});
```

If using external js, then put data in hidden input and get data from that textbox as string and decode in json.

Or the best programming is to use `AJAX`, from where you are using external js.

Comment: I am not sure why, I tried your answer before too. This is a plugin came with whole package. Altering the code resulted into a waste of 10 hrs.

Comment: I tried json parse before, Downloaded this plugin and tried altering it's source code too! And this plugin is mostly written in AJAX